# How can my Python program avoid minimizing itself when the user clicks on its button?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, tkinter, minimize

I have a made a very simple program that opens a new tab in the user's default browser, here:

```
import tkinter as tk 
import webbrowser


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')
root.title("Bulkdozer")

def open_chrome_tab():
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://google.com')

#####BUTTON ZONE#######
open_browser = tk.Button(root, width=20,  text="Open New Tab", command=open_chrome_tab)
open_browser.grid(row=22, column=1)
#####BUTTON ZONE END#######
root.mainloop()
```

However, when the user clicks on the `Open New Tab` button, the GUI of this program minimizes itself immediately while opening the corresponding new tab in the user's default browser.

How can I set a rule that make this program not minimize itself when the user clicks on its button?

Comment: Try `root.attributes('-topmost',1)`

Comment: The tkinter window keeps open in my Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you sir, may you post that reply as answer to give you a check? that solved my issue after typing that statement under ```root.title("Bulkdozer")``` @CoolCloud

Comment: I see @acw1668, I use Windows 10 and it didn't keep it on my machine. :(

Comment: Are you sure it is minimized? May be it is covered by the browser window.

Comment: Hmph, actually you are right, however, I would have ended up asking how to keep the GUI of this program in front of any window after pressing that button  @acw1668

Comment: Check updated answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way around is to make your window topmost always:

```py
root.attributes('-topmost',True)
```

Or you can use this hack to temporarily give focus and then remove focus once the browser is up.

```
def open_chrome_tab():
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://google.com')
    root.attributes('-topmost',1)
    root.after(1000,lambda: root.attributes('-topmost',0)) # 1000 ms might be delayed depending on time to load browser
```

Comment: For second case, simply call `root.after(1000, root.deiconify)` works in my Window 10.

Comment: @acw1668 Sadly doesn't do the same in windows 11. I tried many other libraries like `pygetwindow` and `win32gui`, none of those could bring the window to foreground.