# Outlook window overtakes python app when launching from tkinter application

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, modal-dialog, pywin32

While this is not app-breaking behavior, it's slightly inconvenient. I am currently writing an application to be used in my organization for managing major incidents. Part of this application uses Outlook to preformat emails, making the process take less mental energy.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

def open_calendar_meeting(subject, default_meeting_recipients):
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = default_meeting_recipients
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HTMLBody = teams_meeting_string_1
    mail.Display(True)
```

Unfortunately, it is not feasible to preformat every bit of text for this email and simply send it with the click of a button. Right now, this code opens outlook, inserts recipients, subject, the body of the email and then forces it display, but is there any way to make the application release its "bind" to the outlook application allowing continue working within the app while the Outlook window is open?

Comment: Do you mean that your application window should stay in front and the Outlook window should be behind it?

Comment: this code doesn't define what `outlook` is. Is that a third party library? What does the documentation say about whether it can be opened in the background?

Comment: @mkrieger1
-  No, sorry. When this code is ran, the tkinter app essentially freezes and is unusable until the window closes

Comment: @BryanOakley - win32com is a Windows API module. Most of the coding in it is guess work, unfortunately. Good catch on the outlook, I forgot to include that line of code. Apologies!

Comment: You can use [`exchangelib`](https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/) to send email via Exchange Server directly which does not require to open Outlook window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can my Python program avoid minimizing itself when the user clicks on its button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70693214/how-can-my-python-program-avoid-minimizing-itself-when-the-user-clicks-on-its-bu)

Comment: Thank you, but the outlook windows HAS to open.

Comment: What happens if you just use `mail.Display()`. The ‘True’ parameter makes the displayed window Modal ie. it blocks everything else, which seems to be the exact opposite of the behaviour you want! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.display

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to start a separate thread to control Outlook. The worker thread will start and display the new email, but control will immediately return to the main thread.

```
from threading import Thread
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

#Task to send an email, with given subject
def createMail(subject):
    print('Starting createMail task') 
    
    #Need to initialize COM for each thread (unless main thread)
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()

    #Attach to the Outlook application
    ol = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

    mail = ol.CreateItem(0)
    mail.Subject = subject

    #Display() will block until the mail window is closed (eg Send is pressed)
    mail.Display(True)

    print('Ending createMail task')

#Main thread
print('Starting main thread')

#Create a worker thread for the createMail task, passing the parameter(s)
t = Thread(target=createMail,args=['Hello World!'])

#Start the worker thread. This is will return immediately
t.start()

print('Ending main thread')
```

Output:

```
Starting main thread
Ending main thread
Starting createMail task
```

Then when the Outlook window has been closed:

```
Ending createMail task
```

Notes:

1. You have to explicitly initialize COM for each worker thread. It is done automatically for the main thread.
2. While it is tempting to create the Outlook object in the main thread (once) and then pass as a parameter to `createMail` this can cause issues with COM.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this with `tkinter`. If your code has a message loop (which it probably does) then maybe the `asyncio` package is a better route than using `Thread`. Perhaps others can advise.

Comment: This is an amazing answer. I will test this out tomorrow and get back to you. Thank you very much! I do not entirely understand your answer however, I will do some googling to help me understand and have some friends to bounce this answer off of who I know will be able to help. Again, much appreciated!

Comment: @CanisVY See comment above … using a worker thread may not be needed.

Comment: Removing true unfortunately produces the same behavior